# Convertir query de MySQL a sintaxis de laravel

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Tengo la siguiente consulta y necesito convertirla a eloquent o query builder, que este protegida contra inyecciones sql.

```
SELECT 
    (select count(*) 
    from users u 
    join solicitudes s on u.id=s.user_id 
    where s.id not in(select s.id 
                            from solicitudes s 
                            join prestamos p on s.id=p.solicitude_id) 
                            and u.id=1) + 
                     (select count(*) 
                            from users u 
                            join solicitudes s on u.id=s.user_id 
                            join prestamos p ON s.id=p.solicitude_id 
                            where u.id=1 and p.observaciones='Reclamado') 
                      as Cantidad 
FROM dual
```

Trate con DB pero no me funciona

```
$parametro = DB::raw('select 
(select count(*) from users u 
join solicitudes s on u.id=s.user_id 
where s.id not in (select s.id from solicitudes s 
                   join prestamos p on s.id=p.solicitude_id) and u.id=AquíVaParametro) + 
                  (select count(*) from users u 
                  join solicitudes s on u.id=s.user_id 
                  join prestamos p on s.id=p.solicitude_id 
                  where u.id=AquíVaParametro and p.observaciones="Reclamado") AS cantidad 
from dual');
```

El error es el siguiente: Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Database\Query\Expression as array

He tratado de acceder de diferentes formas a la variable pero no puedo obtener su valor.

```
$parametro->cantidad
$parametro[0]
$parametro[0]->cantidad
```

Espero que la consulta sea lo mas seguro y creo que esto se consigue con query builder o eloquent. Cualquier ayuda me servirá.

De esta forma la consulta sirve, pero creo que no es nada segura contra inyecciones sql

```
DB::select('select (select count(*) from users u 
join solicitudes s on u.id=s.user_id 
where s.id not in (select s.id from solicitudes s 
                   join prestamos p on s.id=p.solicitude_id) 
                   and u.id='. $request->get('user_id').') + 
                  (select count(*) from users u 
                  join solicitudes s on u.id=s.user_id 
                  join prestamos p on s.id=p.solicitude_id 
                  where u.id='.$request->get('user_id').' 
                  and p.observaciones="Reclamado") 
AS cantidad from dual')
```

Answer (score 1):

Replantee la consulta y cambie raw por select, además de mejorar la seguridad evitando inyecciones sql utilizando parámetros en la consulta, los cuales pase como segundo parámetro de la función mediante un arreglo de clave valor.

```
    $verificacion_parametro = DB::select('select (select count(*) from users u 
                                     join solicitudes s on u.id=s.user_id 
                               where s.id not in (select s.id from solicitudes s 
                       join prestamos p on s.id=p.solicitude_id) and u.id=:id) + 
                           (select count(*) from users u 
                           join solicitudes s on u.id=s.user_id 
                           join prestamos p on s.id=p.solicitude_id 
                   where u.id=:u_id and p.observaciones="Reclamado") AS cantidad 
                   from dual', ['id'=>$request->get('user_id'), 'u_id' => 
                   $request->get('user_id')]);
```

Necesitaba dos veces el mismo parametro dentro de la consulta pero no es posible nombrarlos igual, por eso el arreglo tiene dos elementos que tienen el mismo valor.

Y para acceder a mi consulta es de la siguiente forma.

```
$verificacion_parametro[0]->cantidad
```